# Metadata issue with multiple models & Breeze contexts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, metadata, breeze

Has anyone else tried using the server-side component of Breeze.js in a solution with multiple Api Controllers for multiple EF Models?

I'm finding that after calling the MetaData endpoint on one context, all subsequent calls to MetaData endpoints in other contexts return the MetaData from the first context which was called, for example say I have two Api Controllers, each with their own MetaData endpoint:

```
public class CoreController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<CoreEntities> contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<CoreEntities>();
}

public class FormsController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<FormsEntities> contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<FormsEntities>();
}
```

Calling ~/Core/MetaData will return the JSON for the Core model, however a subsequent call to ~/Forms/MetaData will not return the Forms JSON, but instead the Core metadata is returned. If I call them in reverse I get the Forms metadata both times, this issue appears to persist until the host process is recycled.

I can confirm that I am able to access object data from both models as expected, so I doubt this is a routing issue.

Perhaps someone can tell me if there is some caching going on somewhere which I need to disable?

Regards,

Tom Tregenna

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. We have confirmed the bug and are looking at it. Stay tuned.

Comment: Hi Ward, thanks for your comment, as a quick workaround I've removed lines 24 and 26 from the ContextProvider base class in Breeze.WebApi, where the null check on _jsonMetadata takes place:

        if (__jsonMetadata == null) {
          __jsonMetadata = BuildJsonMetadata();
        }

I admit, I have no idea what else this might affect, but until an updated version becomes available, do you see any glaring issues in doing this?

Regards, Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this should be fixed in Breeze 0.73.4, available either via nuget or zips on the breeze website.

Comment: @TomT - Should be fixed now. If Jay's answer (and fix) satisfied you, please click the tick mark under the up/down to indicate that you accept it. If not, let us know and we'll keep digging. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You are right. I've tested this issue and this behaviour you reported happened. Putting breakpoints for each `Metadata()` method for the two Controllers, and using Fiddler, I concluded that **this is not a routing issue**. The two Controllers are using differents Context (`contextProvider`'s property), but the first Metadata  that was called is always returned. I guess this is Breeze's library issue. I've read the Breeze's documentation, but I have not found anything that could help.

Answer (score 0):

There is another issue with the same symptoms. It is related to ambiguous references to the Entity Framework metadata in the connection string. I had two separate EDMX files, both of which were named Model.edmx (separate projects). When I referenced the assembly that contained the second EDMX file, the connection string below became ambiguous - the metadata files from both of the EDMX files fit the description.

```
metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;
```

I was able to resolve the issue by renaming one of the EDMX files.

An alternative solution would be to replace the asterisk with the full name of the assembly which contains the embedded metadata - there is actually a performance benefit to doing so. See the MSDN documentation covering [Entity Framework connection strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716756%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for further details.

> assemblyFullName
>
> The full name of an assembly with the embedded resource. The name
>   includes the simple name, version name, supported culture, and public
>   key, as follows:
>
> ResourceLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>
> Resources can be embedded in any assembly that is accessible by the
>   application.
>
> If you specify a wildcard (*) for assemblyFullName, the Entity
>   Framework runtime will search for resources in the following
>   locations, in this order:
>
> The calling assembly.
>
> The referenced assemblies.
>
> The assemblies in the bin directory of an application.
>
> If the files are not in one of these locations, an exception will be
>   thrown.
>
> Cc716756.note(en-us,VS.100).gifNote:  When you use wildcard (*), the
>   Entity Framework has to look through all the assemblies for resources
>   with the correct name. To improve performance, specify the assembly
>   name instead of the wildcard.